# Bootstrap toggle (navbar) is not working on first load React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with my bootstrap navbar. It is not working on first load. But if I refresh the page, it is working perfectly. I am new to reactjs and this is my first attempt to create a project.

The scenario is after successful log in, it will redirect to dashboard page.

Please check my code below:
**HomePage.jsx**

```
 render() { 
    ...
    <button className="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right d-lg-none align-self-center" type="button" data-toggle="offcanvas">
      <span className="mdi mdi-menu"></span>
    </button>
   ...
    function mapStateToProps(state) {
        const { feeds, authentication } = state;
        const { user } = authentication;
        return {
            user,
            feeds
        };
    }

    const connectedHomePage = connect(mapStateToProps, null, null, {
        pure: false
    })(HomePage);
    export { connectedHomePage as HomePage };
```

Can you help me figure out what is wrong with this? I have already set the required js libs for the off-canvas thing in **index.html**.

```
<script src="../public/js/off-canvas.js"></script>
<script src="../public/js/popper.min.js"></script>
```

**Index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>App</title>
        <!-- plugins:css -->

        <!-- inject:css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/css/style.css" />

        <!-- To fix issue in multiple path parameters -->
        <base href="/" />

        <!-- endinject:css -->
        <style>
            a { cursor: pointer; }
            .help-block { font-size: 12px; }
        </style>
        <!-- Add to home screen for Safari on iOS -->
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Kingfisher Group Users App">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="../public/img/logo.png">

        <!-- Tile Icon for Windows -->
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="../public/img/logo.png">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#2F3BA2">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <!-- plugins:js -->
        <script src="../public/vendors/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../public/vendors/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../public/vendors/node_modules/perfect-scrollbar/dist/perfect-scrollbar.min.js"></script>

        <!-- endinject -->
        <!-- inject:js -->
        <script src="../public/js/off-canvas.js"></script>
        <script src="../public/js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../public/js/hoverable-collapse.js"></script>
        <script src="../public/js/misc.js"></script>
        <!-- endinject -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

But there's still something missing. Please help as I am stuck in this problem and can't move forward. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: i didn't get `It is not working on first load.`,what you wanted it to look like

Comment: @karthik Of course I want to make it work on first load of the page. As I said the navbar is only working after page refresh.

Comment: Share your index.html

Comment: @Think-Twice done please check my index.html

Comment: Can you try moving all your scripts after body close tag and before html close tag and try. I had same issue in the past and after moving my scripts after body close tag worked for me

Comment: @Think-Twice DId that to no avail.

Comment: I am not getting that

Comment: @Think-Twice I meant I did move all my scripts after body close tag and before html close tag but still not working.

Comment: Okey that could be one possible reason which I think.

Comment: @Think-Twice yes that's why there's something else going on here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correct, in general you should use different components for different condition - either logged of no.

Thus is should be something like this:

```
render() {
  if (this.props.user) {
    return (<ConponentForLoggedInState>)
  }
  return (<LoginPageComponent>)
}
```

Comment: I think this doesn't help my problem

Comment: Then what should toggler do?

Comment: It should work as expected. It should display the links.